# How to get page number in Yii

Tags: yii

I am using Yii to show a list page, which is shown in several pages automatic via zii.widgets.CListView.

When the user click the next page, the url does not change. But I need to know which page the user is viewing.

How can I get the page number in Yii?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Disable Ajax on CViewList with**  'ajaxUpdate'=>false

You wont get the current page number directly because of the ajax calls. If you disable the ajax from CListView you can able to get the current page numbers on page load.

**My Sample controller**

```
     <?php
     $dataProvider = new CActiveDataProvider('MyModel', array('pagination' => array('pageSize' => 3)));
     $this->render('MyViewPage', array('dataProvider' => $dataProvider));
     ?>
```

**Now Check my View**

```
    <?php
    $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', 
        array(
                'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
                'ajaxUpdate'=>false
            ));

    echo "Current Page Number is: ".(int)($dataProvider->pagination->getCurrentPage()+1);
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the zero-based [`currentPage`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CPagination#currentPage-detail) attribute of the `pagination`

```
...
'pagination'=>array(
  'pageSize'=>2,
  'currentPage'=>1,
),
...
```

`currentPage` returns the zero-based index of the current page.

Try to get the current page number like `$cuurentPage=>$pages->currentPage+1,` in view page.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I am not clear on your point. My question should be, is there anything like CPagination->getPageNum() to get the current page number?

Answer (score 0):

You get the current page from the `CPagination` object of your data provider:

```
$provider = $model->search();
$page = $provider->pagination->currentPage;
```

Comment: I can get the page parameter, but it is always 0. What's wrong?